# Having trouble with template classes having template member functions

Tags: c++

In my experimentation with templates I've come across a confusing predicament. I'm defining a templated struct `F` who default argument is `int`. It has a templated member function `g`. I'm defining it below the struct definition. I figured this was the correct way to go about it, however, I receive an error. And only one error:

> prog.cpp:9:62: error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing 'void F<  >::g()'

```
template <typename = int> struct F {

    template <typename> void g();

};

template <typename T = int> template <typename> void F<T>::g() {}

int main() {

    F<>f;

}
```

It's quite vague. I couldn't exactly understand what it means. So I tried changing some things around. I figured it was the default template arguments for the definition of `F`. So I changed:

```
template <typename = int> struct F {
```

to

```
template <typename T = int> struct F {
```

I also tried giving `g` template arguments:

```
template <typename T = int> template <typename U> void F<T>::g<U>() {}
```

But then I received the errors:

> prog.cpp:9:67: error: function template partial specialization 'g' is not allowed
>   prog.cpp:9:67: error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing 'void F::g()'

I even tried specifying that `g` was a template function:

```
template <typename T = int> template <typename U> void F<T>::template g<U>() {}
```

But it didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Default template parameters must be used only on function declarations, not on definitions:

```
template <typename T/* = int*/> template <typename> void F<T>::g() {}
```

Comment: Which is consistent with function argument default parameters.

Comment: But... the default parameter does appear in a definition, namely that of `F`. Not to mention the rules for function default parameters are more lenient than those for template default parameters.